# Python nested loop overwriting rather than appending to list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe based on nested for loops (two loops). The lower loop with variable "tag" is working perfectly thanks to @Andrej Kesely. The top loop with variable "date" is also working, however it just overwrites previous data from the bottom loop rather than simply appending the new data to the bottom of the list from the previous bottom loop output. Would be very grateful for your help in fixing this. Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd    
from datetime import timedelta, date

url = 'https://oilpriceng.net/' #03-09-2019/


def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for day in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(day)

start_date = date(2019,9,3)
end_date = date(2019,9,8)

for date in daterange(start_date, end_date):

    date = date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url+str(date)+'/').content, 'html.parser')
    df = []

    data, last = {'Enterprise':[], 'Price NGN':[], 'Product':[]}, ''
    for tag in soup.select('h1 strong, tr:has(td.vc_table_cell)'):
        if tag.name == 'strong':
            last = tag.get_text(strip=True)
        else:
            a, b = tag.select('td')
            a, b = a.get_text(strip=True), b.get_text(strip=True)
            if a and b != 'DEPOT PRICE':
                data['Enterprise'].append(a)
                data['Enterprise'].append(data['Enterprise'])
                data['Price NGN'].append(b)
                data['Price NGN'].append(data['Price NGN'])
                data['Product'].append(last)
                data['Product'].append(data['Product'])
                data['Date'] = date


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.append(df)

df.to_csv("White_Product_Price.csv")
df.head(10)
```

Comment: Did you mean to put: `data = {'Enterprise':[], 'Price NGN':[], 'Product':[]}` before: `for date in daterange(... :`?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't do: `data['Enterprise'].append(data['Enterprise'])` (et al) since this makes a recursive list.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana I want the loop, through: 
    data = {'Enterprise':[], 'Price NGN':[], 'Product':[]}: for each date and append each dates output at the end of the previous dates' Hope i've got that order right...